# Можно ли сделать перезапуск уровня, когда уничтожается один из игроков?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ребята, помогите! Суть в чем: У меня есть два игрока, которые при столкновении с врагом уничтожаются, но перезапуск уровня не происходит!
Если удалить в коде момент Destroy, то уровень перезапускается.
Что делать??

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    { 
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
            {
               
               Instantiate(deathplayer, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
               StartCoroutine (WaitForIt (1.0F)); 
               Destroy(gameObject);

            }
    }   
           
     IEnumerator WaitForIt(float waitTime)
        {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
```

Comment: Добавьте код к вопросу, пожалуйста

Comment: Может перезапуск нужно к другому объекту привязать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. У меня тоже была такая проблема, пока я не разобрался нормально с корутинами.На всякий случай дам [ссылку](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Coroutines.html).

ЧТО ТАКОЕ КОРУТИНА:
Корутина при вызове может выжидать определенное время, после чего выполнять свой код. ПРИЧЕМ, тот код, откуда она была вызвана продолжает выполнение. В данном случае ваш код работает так:

1. Срабатывает метод `OnCollisionEnter()`, срабатывает проверка if
2. Срабатывает функция `Instantiate()`
3. Вызывается корутина `WaitForIt()`
4. Корутина **ЖДЕТ** 1 секунду, НО код в методе `OnColisionEnter()` продолжает выполнение, из-за чего срабатывает функция `Destroy()`, удаляющая объект на котором висит этот скрипт. Объект удален - корутина не успевает сработать, так как 1 секунда, которую она должна была ждать, еще не прошла. В итоге ваш объект просто удаляется.

Просто поймите, что при вызове *корутин*ы, код в том месте, где вы ее вызвали, **продолжает выполнение**, в то время как корутина **делает что-то свое или, допустим, ждет.**

Ваш код исправляется простейшим образом: просто перетаскиваем строку `Destroy(gameObject);` в конец корутины. Теперь корутина будет ждать секунду, загружать сцену и удалять объект.

Я вам более того скажу, вам можно (хотя на 100% я не уверен) вообще удалить функцию `Destroy()`, т.к. при выполнении команды `SceneManager.LoadScene` ваша сцена полностью перезагружается, такчто объекты на старой сцене удалятся сами собой.

Comment: Максим, благодарю вас за ответ! Ваше решение действительно помогло.

Comment: Destroy(gameObject); мне нужна для того, чтобы показать смерть героя. Предложенный вами метод действительно работает, но персонаж не исчезает при смерти (как было задумано). Можно ли сделать так, чтобы персонаж вначале исчезал, а потом уже перезагружался уровень?

Comment: Ну конечно. Но для этого его не надо уничтожать, потому что в таком случае скрипты на нем останавливаются. Вам надо просто делать игрока невидимым любым способом, например, с помощью transform.SetActive(false). Скрипты продолжат выполнение, но объект пропадет. Порядок действий: игрок исчезает, показываем сто вы там хотите, ждем, перезагружаем сцену.

Comment: Обращаю ваше внимание на две вещи: первое, корутина может ждать несколько раз, то есть сделали что-то, подождали, сделали, пождали , можно и в цикле. Второе: ну... типа... если мой ответ вам помог, то поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку, чтобы принять его. Это даст другим понять, что вопрос закрыт